# Change an exe file's compatibility settings with C#

Tags: c#, windows, exe, admin, compatibility

How can I change an exe file's compatibilty settings in c#? I want to change the compatibility mode of the program and run the program as administrator. I haven't found any working solutions yet.

[image: settings i want to change on the exe file]

Comment: That's the user decision, not the program's.

Comment: If you could do that with a user mode program then it would be a **very** serious vulnerability for the operating system. Malware has to trick the user into clicking yes to "destroy my system and steal my identity" or exploit a vulnerability that is unknown to virus checkers. Zero day exploits are highly prized by the bad guys (and GCHQ).

Comment: Compatibility mode is a hack for programs that were written for older OSs, especially when they expect to have the run of the system like they did in a pre-UAC world. If your program needs to run with administrator privileges (which, as Alejandro said, is the user's decision), you need to provide the appropriate request for admin permissions in the manifest so Windows can present the UAC dialog.